# MvvmCross Dialog select from a list (combobox)

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, monotouch.dialog

There is no support for selecting from a list in MOnotouch.dialog. I have searched for anything that can be amended to be used in MvvmCross.Dialog but there seems to be nothing that even works with iOS7.

Has anyone managed to solve this problem? ATM I'd live with anything that got the job done (UIPickerView, radio group) whatever really. I just haven't managed to find anything that works. I'm loathed to roll my own if this is a solved problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radio group provides the functionality to pick an item inside a list in monotouch.dialog 
It's used in the "Dessert" selection in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/DialogExamples/DialogExamples.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs - I just tested this sample on ios7 and it seems to be working for me

Comment: I'll go this route - have a feeling the client will want something hosted in an action sheet akin to the datepicker but let's see :)